# Learning AJAX, html code won't do anything

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have set up a servlet displaying usernames,passwords,wins,and losses for a checkersgame I wrote. I want to create a ajax program to access this page and create a table listing the users wins and losses (like a simple leader board). However my HTML code won't work and I can't see why. I can log into the page that I list as the variable url and see the xml file from the servlet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function requestUpdate()
{
    var req = newXMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function()
    {   
        if(req.readyState == 4)
        {
            displayResult(req);
        }
    }
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/Checkers/CheckersServlet"; 
    req.open("GET",url,true);
    req.send(null);
}

function displayResult(req)
{
    var div = document.getElementById("Scoreboard");
    div.innerHTML = "<table border> <tr> <th> Username </th> <th> Wins </th> <th> Losses </th> </tr>" ;

    var doc = req.responseXML;
    var Users = doc.getElementsByTagName('Username');
    var Wins = doc.getElementsByTagName('Wins');
    var Losses = doc.getElementsByTagName('Losses');
    var U;
    var W;
    var L;
    for(var i = 0; i < Users.length; i++)
    {
        U = Users.item(i).textContent;
        W = Wins.item(i).textContent;
        L = Losses.item(i).textContent;

        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<tr> <td>" + U + "</td> <td>" + W + "</td> <td>" + L + "</td> </tr>";
    }

div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "</table>";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload = "requestUpdate()">
    <button onclick = "requestUpdate()">Update</button>
    <div id = "Scoreboard"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the servlet code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CheckersServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/CheckersServlet")
public class CheckersServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public CheckersServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("text/xml");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<?xml version='1.0'?>" );

    BufferedReader fReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/adamsturge991/desktop/checkersdatabase.txt"));
    String data = fReader.readLine();
    out.println("<CheckersData>");
    while(data != null)
    {
        out.println("<User>");
        out.println("<Username>");
        out.println(data); 
        out.println("</Username>");
        data = fReader.readLine();
        out.println("<Password>");
        out.println(data);
        out.println("</Password>");
        data = fReader.readLine();
        out.println("<Wins>");
        out.println(data);
        out.println("</Wins>");
        data = fReader.readLine();
        out.println("<Losses>");
        out.println(data);
        out.println("</Losses>");
        out.println("</User>");
        data = fReader.readLine(); //get next username or null if end of database
    }
    out.println("</CheckersData>");
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

Comment: You should look into http://www.jquery.com. It'll simplify most of this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
var req = newXMLHttpRequest();
```

Needs a space after `new`, so:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

(Note also that continually updating `div.innerHTML` in your `displayResult()` function will not give good performance. Better to build up the required html in a string variable and then set `div.innerHTML` equal to that variable at the end.)

Comment: Thanks! Although now my code seems to stop at var Users = doc.getElementsByTagName('Username');. I have checked and there are lines at the url such as <Username>Adam</Username>. Any idea what is happening? It appears that var doc = req.responseXML is null, I tried document.write(doc) to see what would happen, and it just wrote the word null. I know that document.write() is meant to take strings however so that might not mean anything

Comment: Does the response from your servlet have a MIME type "text/xml"? (Also, rather than trying to debug with `document.write()` try `console.log()` and open your browser's console to see the results, e.g., ctrl-shift-J to use Chrome's built in dev tools.)

Answer (score 2):

This line :

```
var req = newXMLHttpRequest();
```

Should be :

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

And this line :

```
var doc = req.responseXML;
```

Should be :

```
 var doc = req.responseText;
```

Update:

```
var doc = req.responseText;

/*This is for making XML doc, otherwise `getElementsByTagName` wont work*/
if (window.DOMParser)
{
   parser=new DOMParser();
   xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(doc,"text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(doc);
} 

/*XML DOC is ready, now parse it with `getElementsByTagName1`*/ 
var Users = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Username');
var Wins = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Wins');
var Losses = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Losses');
```

Comment: the file written by the servlet is an xml file. Do I still have to use responceText in that case?

Comment: Yea, your code worked for me after doing so. see the update part.

Comment: Even after doing that it's now telling me that Users.length is 0, sigh

Comment: you could try one thing. just add some hardcoded data in the servlet instead of loading from text file. that will help you to ensure AJAX is correct. I feel like its missing something when you pulling the data from file.

Comment: Nope, even with hard coded data it still says the length is 0 :(

Comment: I saved the website that it's pulling data from, here it is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CheckersData>
<User>
<Username>
Adam
</Username>
<Password>
red
</Password>
<Wins>
2
</Wins>
<Losses>
0
</Losses>
</User>
<User>
<Username>
Ben
</Username>
<Password>
blue
</Password>
<Wins>
0
</Wins>
<Losses>
2
</Losses>
</User>
</CheckersData>

Comment: create a simple xml page, name it `servlet.xml` now add the data you have writen in comments in it. change this line in your code `var url = "http://localhost:8080/Checkers/servlet.xml` now run the page. what it says ?